# java reflection: get list of classes in a package at compile to use at runtime

Tags: java, reflection

I have console application that do some reflection operations on list of classes (log field names, annotations, etc.).

Right now I create list of classnames by hand as strings in a file. I would love to be able to add project/package/configure path to build folder/etc. to my console project, build it and somehow use classnames got during compile in runtime.

Simple usecase: compile my app with a package, run on production site to check if every data class has proper database configuration.

Found this solution:
https://dzone.com/articles/get-all-classes-within-package but it works during runtime and I prefer to get those names during compile time... is it possible? Or am I getting this wrong?

Comment: There is something called an annotation processor (interface `javax.annotation.processing.Processor`), that is like a compile time annotation processing tool, look it up.